# Equivalent paths are not allowed. Swagger 2.0

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, openapi, swagger-2.0, springdoc-openapi-ui

I have two services sharing the same path but with differnt HTTP method
[image]

And here is the diffination

```
swagger: '2.0'
paths:

  /path/{Id}:
    get:
      summary: Get paramName
      parameters:
        - name: Id
          in: path
          required: true
          type: string
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Success  
  /path/{someOtherParamNameButTheVerbIsPost}:
    post:
      summary: Do something
      parameters:
        - name: someOtherParamNameButTheVerbIsPost
          in: path
          required: true
          type: string
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Success
```

When check this schema for errors it returns this one

[image]

Unfortunately it is not possible to modify the definition manually as it is auto generated.

Any suggestion (or workaround) to fix this issue?